# Cyclist detecting player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game and I have a my player with the tag "Player". I have a cyclist spawning system, and each cyclist has the tag "cyclist", they are all prefabs. I have a script on the cyclists prefab that makes it move forwards, so each time it spawns, it instantly begins to move in a fixed direction.

I want the cyclists to be able to detect 2 things, one being if the player is in front of it, and the other if another cyclist is in-front of it. If so, I want the cyclist to stop cyclist. I have a script called cyclistStoping.cs that I'm using to do this. The script has been placed onto the cyclist prefab for multiple instances to be spawned.

Bug

I've noticed that sometimes even once a cyclist(a) is no longer in front of another cyclist(b), cyclist(b) will still remain still, and it will only move off again if the player walks in front of it and then walks off again. I feel like my code is just buggy and would really appreciate some help on this.

I've tried to do 2 simple checks inside each trigger function but some cyclists still remain idle when once the cyclist is no longer in front of them.

I have also tried using a delay function so whenever the cyclist or player are no longer in range, the cyclist doesn't move off until 2-3 seconds have passed. However with this, the cyclist doesn't move off again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cyclistStoping : MonoBehaviour
{

public VehicleMove cyclistMovement;


public bool playerInside = false;
public bool cyclistInside = false;

private bool timePassed = false;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{

}

// implement delay

// player or cyclist (INSIDE)
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" ) {
        playerInside = true;
        cyclistInside = false;
    }

    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Cyclist")
    {
        playerInside = false;
        cyclistInside = true;
    }

    if (playerInside == true || cyclistInside == true) {
        Debug.Log("Player inside: " + playerInside);
        cyclistMovement.vehicleMovement = 0.0f;

    }
}

// player or cyclist (EXIT)
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        playerInside = false;
        cyclistInside = false;
    }

    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Cyclist")
    {
        playerInside = false;
        cyclistInside = false;
    }

    if (playerInside == false || cyclistInside == false)
    {

        if (timePassed == true) {
            Debug.Log("Player inside: " + playerInside);
            cyclistMovement.vehicleMovement = 0.1f;
            // delay, then move off
            timePassed = false;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator timeDelay()
{
    // wait before moving off
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    timePassed = true;
}

}
```

I expect the cyclist to stop if a player is in front of it, and once the next cyclist spawn, I expect THAT cyclist to stop once it detects the first cyclist. Once the player moves away from the first cyclist, it should take 2 seconds before moving off, and the second cyclist will do exactly the same.

Comment: TriggerEnters and CollisionEnters are quite buggy to my oppinion, It can happen that an object triggers itself, or that two objects trigger at the same time, or before the other object is outside of the trigger. This can make problems in you code if you change an object on enter and on exit, when there are 2 objects inside your trigger and one is leaving, then you code might say, object has left, Start code, yet there is another object still in your trigger.
I don't really know your usecase, but in these cases a TriggerStay can help u determine if there is still an object inside.

Comment: You should take a look at NavMeshAgents, it's exactly what you want to achieve. It include pathfinding, obstacle avoidance and much more/

Comment: time to add some debugging statements to recreate the issue, as @Jichael says, navmesh agents sound like they should do all this for you, reinventing the wheel could be unnecessary

Comment: Your problem also maybe you dont seem to call timeDelay... and because it only sets speed if timedlay is true as the exit happens.. if timedlay is false at any other point which seems to be the default, timedelay is never true as it exits - also if it exits and the delay was false the cyclist never starts again

Comment: Cross-post: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/169945/cyclist-detecting-player

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that the logic to make the bike move again should be in the `IEnumerator`, not the `OnTriggerExit`. Start the `Coroutine` in `OnTriggerExit`:

```
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        playerInside = false;
    }

    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Cyclist")
    {
        cyclistInside = false;
    }

    if (playerInside == false && cyclistInside == false) 
    {
        StartCoroutine(timeDelay());
    }

}
```

And check again in the `IEnumerator`:

```
IEnumerator timeDelay()
{
    // wait before moving off
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

    if (playerInside == false && cyclistInside == false) {
        cyclistMovement.vehicleMovement = 0.1f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for this. This seems to have fixed the issue for the cyclists moving off, but there are still times when they don't move off even once the player is no longer in front.

Comment: I don't see what else could be wrong with the code. Maybe two bikes are stopping each other, after they collide? Could also be that OnTriggerExit is just somehow buggy in your specific case